# Flickering text in Safari with bxslider

Tags: javascript

in Safari the text in the sidebar flickers to a different color every time the slideshow transitions. Only happening in sidebar on safari with black background and white text. Also I am on a mac, not sure if this happens on windows safari as well.

Url is: http://isabodychallenge.com

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that by adding:

useCSS: false

to js settings for bxslider fixes this issue.